# process.env.PWD doesn't work on mupx deploy

Tags: meteor, deployment, server, meteor-up

I have this code in my Meteor project on the server. It loads a font file into a PDF generating package:

`doc.font(process.env.PWD + '/public/[...]');`

This works fine on my local machine but in deployment I get this error logged:

`Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/bundle/bundle/public/[...]'`

The PDF package is using fs.readFileSync to try and read this file.

I'm deploying using mupx [the dev branch of Meteor Up which uses Docker].

Why would process.env.PWD no longer correctly reference the correct root of my project? Is the issue related to the build scripts that mup[x]/Meteor does to create production versions of Meteor apps?

Comment: Have you found a good way of solving that? We´re running into the same issues here...

Comment: @thomasf1 we are using the approach in my answer below, seems to be fine thru one mupx update but we are holding off meteor updates for this project. If you can come up with something better please leave and answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find how to do this / perhaps there is not a Meteor way to do this yet. So my current solution is to check for production/development and set a variable for the prefix:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  prefix = process.env.PWD + '/public';
} else {
  prefix = '/bundle/bundle/programs/web.browser/app';
}
```

This prefix variable gets you to /public

Comment: I'm leaving this unaccepted for a few days incase others have better answers

Comment: I have this same issue. It looks like compiler transpiles process.* variables when doing meteor build. That's what I found when I examined the build files. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Forgot to accept my/this answer after no alternatives were presented. @DeepakMittal the now accepted answer worked for us

Comment: any way to get path on server not for the public folder, but newly created /.files folder, that is not watched by Meteor for changes?

Comment: @mhlavacka deploy mupx, log into the server and then docker instance and find where your files folder is then get the path is probably the best way using this answer as a solution

Comment: thanks for your reply! I'd, but don't your app gets restarted every time you save something to public?

Comment: But using /public folder restarts your app on the client every time something is saved there. In order to prevent this you have to use /.uploads, bc dot folders are invisible for changes

Answer (score 0):

By default, the public directory is usually located something akin to ./programs/web.browser/app/ for a Mup app.

The private directory i believe is located at ./programs/server/assets/app/.

So, using the server side file structure - (obviously this is run on  a server based method - such as Meteor.methods) and private files (put your fonts at /private/fontfile.xss').

```
var font_file_name = 'fontfile.xxx';
var server_root = Npm.require('fs').realpathSync( process.cwd() );
var font_path = server_root + '/assets/app/' + font_file_name;
```

This should work on both servers, and your local operations.

Comment: The realpathSync(process.cwd()) does yield "/Users/x/Dev/rentkit/.meteor/local/build/programs/server" on dev, which is not the root of the project, but the build directory...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way :

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  routePath = fs.realpathSync('./../../../../../public');
})
```

but instead of `public` I used `.uploads`. Creating `.uploads` on project level next to public. The advantage is that your Meteor app doesn't watch .uploads for changes every single time.